# Progress-MS01 docking incident

Tags: iss, progress

I read somewhere that the last [Progress-MS01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_MS-01) strongly misfired completely to side just after docking to ISS which created problems for future Soyuz missions. Why did this happen? What was the effect  on the ISS and future structural airlock safety?

Answer (score 3):

You can read detailed accounts of the event e.g. on [RussianSpaceWeb.com](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/progress-ms.html#toru) and [NASASpaceFlight.com](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2016/07/progress-ms-01-departs-following-off-nominal-test/). During a manual docking exercise, the spacecraft pitched while already in contact with the docking port, due to apparently unexpected thruster firings. However, Roskosmos nevertheless considered the exercise as success.

The SSVP docking system [is designed to withstand accidental loads during docking](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/docking.html). It doesn't seem to have caused any lasting damage, and [Progress MS-03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_MS-03) docked to the same port only two weeks afterwards.